# How can I create responsive JList in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to create a shop by having a main `JPanel` that each component inside it is a `JPanel` with an image, label and button.

I did tried using a `JList` but the problem with the `JList` its only holds the rendering of the component and because of that the button isn't working and its only an image. I can walk around and use MouseEvent but it feels wrong for me and I am sure that there is a better solution for it.

I want that the components will change their positions depend on the frame size, like in the `JList`.

For example, if I change from the width of the screen the positions of the components will change from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I do have an idea by using `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` in the `paintComponent` (because it calls every rendering. If you know another method that calls every rendering int the `JPanel` I would like to know) and changing the positions of the components by changing the layout variables inside the `paintComponent`.

I did surfed the internet to find a solution but I only found that people used `JTable` but I don't see it working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each component inside it is a JPanel with an image, label and button.

Makes sense.

> changing the positions of the components by changing the layout variables inside the paintComponent.

The paintComponent() method has nothing to do with changing the layout of the panels. You should not be playing with the paintComponent() method.

> I do have an idea by using GridLayout or GridBagLayout

You are correct to use a layout manager, but unfortunately, none of the default layout managers will wrap automatically at a random number of components.

The layout managers are invoked automatically as the frame is resized.

So you can use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which is an extension to the FlowLayout that will allow random wrapping.

Comment: Thx, I will try it.